# How do I download CakePHP 1.3 from the CakePHP GitHub repository?

Tags: cakephp

I am working on a legacy CakePHP 1.3 project and would like to follow the [standard blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Tutorials-Examples/Blog.html).

**The tutorial says this is possible in 2 ways:**

a) To download via **http://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/downloads**, however when visiting this link there are no packages to download anything.

b) It suggests that it is possible to download via the command line using **git clone git://github.com/cakephp/cakephp.git**, however this appears to download the latest version (at this stage 2.0+)

I have located what appears to be CakePHP 1.3 at this address https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/1.3, but I am not sure how to download these all in one go with git options.

Answer (score 5):

You can either download one of the [tagged zips](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tags), or simply `checkout` the 1.3 branch after cloning the repository from Git bash:

```
git clone http://github.com/cakephp/cakephp
git checkout 1.3
```

That way you get the 1.3 branch and can use those files. If you ever want to get back to the master branch, simply `checkout` that branch:

```
git checkout master
```

Answer (score 4):

Last CakePHP 1.3.21 zip file:

https://codeload.github.com/cakephp/cakephp/zip/1.3.21

Answer (score 1):

All releases are tagged and you can download them from https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tags